# the smallest algorithm’s asymptotic time complexity as a function of n

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

we have known some of the algorithm’s asymptotic time complexity is a function of n such as

O(log* n), O(log n), O(log log n), O(n^c) with 0< c < 1, ....

May I know what is the **smallest** algorithm’s asymptotic time complexity as a function of n ?

- Update 1 : we look for the asymptotic time complexity function with n. O(1) is the smallest, but it does not have n.
- Update 2: O(1) is the smallest time complexity we can go, but what is the next smallest well-known functions with n ? so far as I research:

  O(alpha (n)) : inverse Ackermann: Amortized time per operation using a disjoint set

  or O(log * n)iterated logarithmic The find algorithm of Hopcroft and Ullman on a disjoint set

Comment: `smallest algorithm's`, what exactly does this mean?

Comment: O(1) -> constant time

Comment: `O(1)` is the smallest possible category, for example an algorithm determining if `n` is odd or even. There can't be anything smaller than `O(1)` because it encompasses the case when you do nothing for every input.

Comment: A lot of algorithms have O(1) complexity, like stack push-pop, returning 1st element from a list, queue push-pop etc. An infinitely ending  list.

Comment: That's similar to asking "what is the smallest real number larger than 1". Can't be answered because there is always yet another number in between.

Comment: The smallest non-O(1) complexity that I know of in a practical algorithm is the [Disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), where the amortized time complexity is the inverse ackerman function. This function gives less than 5 even when `n` is in the trillions of trillions.

Comment: define "well-known function".

Comment: For what it's worth, the Ackermann function grows even more slowly than the iterated logarithm.

Comment: Actually O(1/n) = o(1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from the trivial `O(1)`, the answer is: there isn't one.

If something isn't `O(1)` (that is, with `n -> infinity`, computing time goes to infinity), whatever bounding function of `n` you find, there's always a smaller one: just take a logarithm of the bounding function. You can do this infinitely, hence there's no smallest non-constant bounding function.

However in practice you should probably stop worrying when you reach the [inverse Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse) :)

Answer (score 2):

1. It is not necessary that the complexity of a given algorithm be expressible via well-known functions. Also note that big-oh is not **the** complexity of a given algorithm. It is an upper bound of the complexity.
2. You can construct functions growing as slow as you want, for instance n<sup>1/k</sup> for any k.
3. `O(1)` is as low as you can go in terms of complexity and strictly speaking 1 is a valid function, it simply is constant.

EDIT: a really slow growing function that I can think of is the [iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) as complexity of [disjoint set forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) implemented with both path compression and union by rank.

Comment: yes, O(1) is the smallest we can go, but what is the next smallest well-known functions with n ? so far as I research, it is O(alpha (n) ) or O(log * n), but I am not sure is it correct

Comment: @super1ha1 as I pointed out there is no such function. The lowest I can think of is the iterated logarithm of DSF which is practically linear

Answer (score 1):

There is always a "smaller algorithm" that whatever suggested.

```
O(log log log log(n)) < O(log log log(n)) < O(log log (n)) < O(log(n)).
```

You can put as many `log` as you want. But I don't know if there is real life example of these.

So my answer is you will get closer and closer to `O(1)`.